# Object-oriented implementation of a real-world scenario of using a bathroom - follow-up

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

This is revised code for the previous question: [Object-oriented implementation of a real-world scenario of using a bathroom](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119150/object-oriented-implementation-of-a-real-world-scenario-of-using-a-bathroom)

Is there any object oriented way or design pattern I can use to make this code better? How can a `User` object access all private methods of `Fitting` instance?

This is inspired from *HeadFirst Object Oriented Analysis and Design*. I thought of writing a scenario based OOP. As we humans live in an object oriented world we interact with many different objects in our daily life. Thinking about the scenario of using a bathroom I started writing an OOP for it considering `Bathroom`, `User`, `Fittings`, and `WaterTank` as objects.

**User.java**

```
package user;

import bathroom.BathroomUser;

public class User implements BathroomUser {

    String userName;

    public User(String userName){
        System.out.println("constructing user... " + userName);
        this.userName=userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserName(){
        return userName;
    }

}
```

**Bathroom.java**

```
package bathroom;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import user.User;
import fittings.Fitting;
import fittings.ChromeTap;
import fittings.Tap;
import fittings.Fitting.FittingType;

public class Bathroom {

    BathroomUser user;  
    Map<FittingType, ArrayList<Fitting>> fittingsMap = new HashMap<Fitting.FittingType, ArrayList<Fitting>>();

    public Bathroom(User user, Map<FittingType, ArrayList<Fitting>> fittingsMap){
        System.out.println("constructing bathroom..."); 
        System.out.println("assigning user... " + user.getUserName()+" to bathroom");
        this.user=user;
        System.out.println("adding fittings to bathroom...");
        this.fittingsMap=fittingsMap;
    }

    public Fitting getBathroomFitting(FittingType fittingType,Class<? extends Fitting> fitting) {

        for (Fitting singleFitting : fittingsMap.get(fittingType)) {
            if (fitting.isInstance(singleFitting)) {
                return singleFitting;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**BathroomUser.java**

```
package bathroom;

public interface BathroomUser {

    public String getUserName();

}
```

**Fitting.java**

```
package fittings;

import tank.TankStatusListener;
import tank.WaterTank;
import bathroom.BathroomUser;

public abstract class Fitting implements TankStatusListener {

    WaterTank tank;

    Thread t;

    int value;

    String fittingName;

    public Fitting(WaterTank tank,int value,String fittingName) {
        this.tank=tank;
        this.value=value;
        this.fittingName=fittingName;
    }

    public enum FittingType {
        TAP, SHOWER, SINK;
    }

    public void turnOn(BathroomUser user){
        t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                tank.getWater(value, Fitting.this);

            }
        },fittingName);
        t.start();
    }

    public void turnOff(BathroomUser user)
    {
        t.interrupt();
    }

    public abstract FittingType getFittingType();

}
```

**Tap.java**

```
package fittings;

import tank.WaterTank;
import bathroom.BathroomUser;

public class Tap extends Fitting {

    public Tap(WaterTank tank,int value,String fittingName) {
        super(tank,value,fittingName);
        System.out.println("constructing TAP fitting...");
    }

    @Override
    public FittingType getFittingType() {
        return FittingType.TAP;
    }

    @Override
    public void turnOn(BathroomUser user) {
        super.turnOn(user);
        System.out.println("Tap turned on By: " + user.getUserName());
    }

    public void controlSpeed(){
        System.out.println("Tap Speed Changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void turnOff(BathroomUser user) {
        super.turnOff(user);
        System.out.println("Tap turned off By: " + user.getUserName());
    }

    @Override
    public void TankStatusChanged(int waterLevel) {
        System.out.println("TAP: remaining water: "+waterLevel);
    }

}
```

**ChromeTap.java**

```
package fittings;

import tank.WaterTank;
import bathroom.BathroomUser;

public class ChromeTap extends Fitting {    

    public ChromeTap(WaterTank tank,int value,String fittingName) {
        super(tank,value,fittingName);
        System.out.println("constructing Chrome Tap fitting...");
    }

    @Override
    public void turnOn(BathroomUser user) {
        super.turnOn(user);
        System.out.println("Chrome Tap tured on by: "+user.getUserName());

    }

    @Override
    public FittingType getFittingType() {
        return FittingType.TAP;
    }

    @Override
    public void turnOff(BathroomUser user) {
        super.turnOff(user);
        System.out.println("Chrome Tap turned off by: "+user.getUserName());    
    }

    @Override
    public void TankStatusChanged(int waterLevel) {
        System.out.println("CHROME TAP: remaining water: "+waterLevel);

    }
}
```

**WaterTank.java**

```
package tank;

public class WaterTank {

    int waterAmount;

    int amount;
    TankStatusListener listener;

    public WaterTank(int waterAmount) {
        System.out.println("constructing water tank...");
        this.waterAmount=waterAmount;
    }

    public void getWater(int amount,TankStatusListener listener){
        while(waterAmount>=amount){
            waterAmount=waterAmount-amount;
            listener.TankStatusChanged(waterAmount);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("stopped...");
                break;  
            }
        }
        System.out.println("NO INOUGH WATER: "+waterAmount);
    }

}
```

**TankStatusListener.java**

```
package tank;

public interface TankStatusListener {

    public void TankStatusChanged(int waterLevel);

}
```

**Run.java**

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import fittings.Fitting;
import fittings.Fitting.FittingType;
import fittings.ChromeTap;
import fittings.Tap;
import bathroom.Bathroom;
import tank.WaterTank;
import user.User;

public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<FittingType, ArrayList<Fitting>> fittingsMap = new HashMap<Fitting.FittingType, ArrayList<Fitting>>();

        User rutvik = new User("rutvik");

        WaterTank tank=new WaterTank(111);

        ArrayList<Fitting> fittings=new ArrayList<Fitting>();
        fittings.add(new Tap(tank,8,"TAP"));
        fittings.add(new ChromeTap(tank,13,"CHROME TAP"));

        fittingsMap.put(FittingType.TAP, fittings);

        Bathroom bathroom = new Bathroom(rutvik,fittingsMap);   

        //TURN ON TAP
        bathroom.getBathroomFitting(FittingType.TAP,Tap.class).turnOn(rutvik);

        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        //TURN ON CHROME TAP
        bathroom.getBathroomFitting(FittingType.TAP,ChromeTap.class).turnOn(rutvik);

        try {Thread.sleep(2000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        //TURN OFF TAP
        bathroom.getBathroomFitting(FittingType.TAP,Tap.class).turnOff(rutvik);

        try {Thread.sleep(2000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        //TURN OFF CHROME TAP
        bathroom.getBathroomFitting(FittingType.TAP,ChromeTap.class).turnOff(rutvik);

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: No I am on Java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General

First I appreciate your approach and exercing OOP as it is the most natural way to put reality into a model and final into a program.
I already noticed this question at an earlier state. As I am thinking this is going into the wrong direction I want to butt in.

## Listener Pattern

Your listener pattern is not implemented in the standard way (TankStatusListener). Your WaterTank should have add(TankStatusListener) and remove(TankStatusListener) methods to manage objects that are interested in status changes of your WaterTank. The listeners should NOT given as a parameter(getWater(.., TankStatusListener)). The listeners that are added to the WaterTank should be notified after the status change. It should look like this:

```
public class WaterTank {

    ...

    private Set<TankStatusListener> listeners;

    public void getWater(int amount){
        while(waterAmount>=amount){
            waterAmount=waterAmount-amount;
            notifyOnTankStatusChanged(waterAmount);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("stopped...");
                break;  
            }
        }
        System.out.println("NO INOUGH WATER: "+waterAmount);
    }

    public void add(TankStatusListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void remove(TankStatusListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private void notifyOnTankStatusChanged(int waterAmount) {

        for(TankStatusListener listener: listeners) {
            listener.tankStatusChanged(waterAmount);
        }

    }

    ...

}
```

## Security semantic

User is too strongly tied to the Bathroom. Maybe your User will be using a kitchen next time so in your concept the next interface User is implementing is "KitchenUser". This is infexible (you have to recompile your code) and doesn't really reflect the semantic. It breaks down to that the User is appearing in a room in a Role, and he should only be able to use the room if he has the proper Role. This seems to me a security concept that should be a separated concern.

## Broken abstractions

"Fitting" as an abstraction knows about concrete FittingTypes. So the abstraction got notice of concretions. This breaks the abstraction as you always have to modify the Fitting class if a new concrete Fitting occurs that has a FittingType which is not known. You should at least extract the enum "FittingType" out of "Fitting".

You are managing the bathroom fitting in a bathroon object knowing them as abstract "Fittings". Your Fittings currently can only be turned on or turned off. The "controlSpeed()"-method of the concrete class "Tap" is not accessable. The problem here is: there a some solutions to gain access to this method but they will ALL break the abstraction through a class cast that will lead to unmaintainable code. And it does not reflect reality either.

The real problem is: You mixed meta-modelling with concrete modelling and I think you did not even noticed that. This mismatch causes class casts at that point you change your view. On one hand you want to manage Fittings in an abstract way (Bathroom), on the other hand a User wants to turn on a specific Fitting and maybe control the flow speed (Tap).

**To solve this cleanly you have to keep your abstraction level!!!**

#### Concrete modelling

With that you have to distinguish between the Fittings that differ in there interface. So you have to put Tap and ChromeTap into different buckets as Tap has the controlSpeed()-method to be accessable. Maybe you find an interface that "Tap" can implement that provides the three methods "turnOn", "turnOff" and "controlSpeed". Maybe something like "InfinitelyAdjustable". ChromeTap maybe will implement "Flop". But you have to think about that carefully.

With concrete modelling I do not mean that you should not use abstractions (interfaces or abstract classes). What I mean is all about avoiding class casts and providing clients the interfaces they need and expect.

#### Meta-Modelling

With Meta-Modelling you are modelling your own classes with objects and you become very flexible. In consistent cases you will have never to recompile the code of your problem domain again. I do not suggest to go deeper into this right now. You should do your own reasearch on this if you are familiar with keeping your abstraction level. At this point I only will refer to Wikipedia: [Meta-Modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamodeling)

Comment: *User is too strongly tied to the Bathroom.*  Believe me, that happens when the objects get older.

Comment: I got it... lately, but I got it... rofl